# Problem with reading a .Json File in Kotlin/Android

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I am writing something to read a Json in Android with Kotlin.

The Goal is to either start the ChooseLoginActicity if there is no User.Json available or to otherwise read the Json and start the MainActivity.

The problem is that the line to open the File into a Input Stream always gets an `FileNotFoundException` even if the User.Json exists with the Permission *-rw-rw----* and got created with `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`, by the same Application.

This Function got called in the onCreate Function of the Activity.

```
fun readJsonFile() {
        try {
            val inputStream = openFileInput("User.json")

            val json = inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
            val gson = Gson()
            val user = gson.fromJson(json, User::class.java)

            CurrentUser.initUser(user.id,user.name)
            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            startActivity(Intent(this, ChooseLoginActivity::class.java))
        }
    }
```

Comment: was it written with `openFileOutput("User.json")` (case sensitive) or in a different way? File not found means file not found, permission errors should be different

Comment: "even if the User.Json exists" -- *where* does it exist? Perhaps it exists in a different location than `openFileInput()` uses.

Comment: As far as i can Tell the openFileInput is there to read files that were created with its oposit Part openFileOutput wich created the User.json in an private android location (MODE_PRIVATE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you wrote the correct file name. Pay attention about case sensitivity.
The code itself should work fine.